# How to split the integers and Operators characters from string in python?

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to split the string into integers and operators for doing Infix expression evaluation in python.

**Here is my string:**

```
>>> s = (1-2+3)*5+10/2
```

I tried this to split:

```
>>>list(s)
['(', '1', '-', '2', '+', '3', ')', '*', '5', '+', '1', '0', '/', '2']
```

This is wrong. Since '10' is splitted into '1','0'

I tried alternative:

```
>>> re.findall('[+-/*//()]+|\d+',s)
['(', '1', '-', '2', '+', '3', ')*', '5', '+', '10', '/', '2']
```

This is also went wrong. Since ')*' should be splitted into ')', '*'

Could you help to split the operators and integers from the given expression?

Comment: This is not the right way to parse mathematical expressions.

Comment: @Sniffer Could you point out what *is* the right way?

Comment: s is not a string right now, anyway...

Comment: @flornquake Check the link pointed to by badc0re in his answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not the best solution for infix. Remove the + after [] like:

```
import re
s = "(1-2+3)*5+10/2"
print re.findall('[+-/*//()]|\d+',s)

['(', '1', '-', '2', '+', '3', ')', '*', '5', '+', '10', '/', '2']
```

Try the following link for correct solution: [Simple Balanced Parentheses](https://web.archive.org/web/20130907031051/http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/BasicDS/stacks.html)

```
from pythonds.basic.stack import Stack

def postfixEval(postfixExpr):
    operandStack = Stack()
    tokenList = postfixExpr.split()

    for token in tokenList:
        if token in "0123456789":
            operandStack.push(int(token))
        else:
            operand2 = operandStack.pop()
            operand1 = operandStack.pop()
            result = doMath(token,operand1,operand2)
            operandStack.push(result)
    return operandStack.pop()

def doMath(op, op1, op2):
    if op == "*":
        return op1 * op2
    elif op == "/":
        return op1 / op2
    elif op == "+":
        return op1 + op2
    else:
        return op1 - op2

print(postfixEval('7 8 + 3 2 + /'))
```

Keep in mind that this is a postfix implementation and its just for example. Do the infix by yourself and if you have any difficulties just ask.

Comment: In this link what i get is push the each character inside stack,and pop out the elements after reached closed parenthesis until open parenthesis..We are doing also the same..before that we have to split the expression, so this way being proposed, for splitting the expression into characters do you have alternate idea, before going to stacking?

Comment: Why use an external `stack` library, when a Python list will suffice? Just replace `Stack()` by `[]` and `.push` by `.append`.

Comment: This is the implementation from the book, it is not mine.

Comment: yeah..i understand it..Just want to do some extra statements and methods..so it came in the way..Here I posted my own implementation with some help .please take a look and give your feedback ..Thanks in advance..https://bitbucket.org/nava/utilities/src/539f378cf76f6c15603991fef136b691f66dab4f/Infix_expre_evaluation.py?at=default

Comment: It doesn't seems to have any problems in the calculations, but i don't get what is the purpose of "if operator.div in l" -> line 49

Comment: And as you see from code (from the book) is too simple, idk if this you are making an assignment, but try to keep your code as simple as possible that makes it more readable.

Comment: @badc0re division has more precedence among others

Comment: I know that but it is kind of confusing for me and also this line where you apply the operations l = l[:operindex-1]+[oper(l[operindex-1], l[operindex+1])]+l[operindex+2:]

Comment: I will write the same thing that i wrote in the post, keep in mind that the posted example is an postfix implementation, you have already made a infix implementation just try to refactoring the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
re.findall('[+-/*//()]|\d+',s)
```

You don't need the `+`, since you only want to have one special sign.

Answer (score 0):

Using split:

```
print filter(lambda x: x, re.split(r'([-+*/()])|\s+', s))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can avoid regular expressions, you can try an iterative solution (just a rough code):

```
s = "(1-2+3)*5+10/2"
numbers = "0123456789."

def split_operators(s):
    l = []
    last_number = ""
    for c in s:
        if c in numbers:
            last_number += c
        else:
            if last_number:
                l.append(last_number)
                last_number = ""
            if c:
                l.append(c)
    if last_number:
        l.append(last_number)
    return l

print split_operators(s)
```

result:

```
['(', '1', '-', '2', '+', '3', ')', '*', '5', '+', '10', '/', '2']
```