# Python - extracting split list correctly

Tags: python, list, split, expression

As a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330795/how-to-properly-split-this-list-of-strings), I have an expression such as this:`['(', '44', '+(', '3', '+', 'll', '))']` which was created by using `re.findall('\w+|\W+',item)` method, however within this list of strings, there are two errors. One is the '+(' and the other is the '))'.

Is there a pythonic way that I could split just the operators such that the list would be something like `['(', '44', '+','(', '3', '+', 'll', ')',')']`.

(keep the digits/letters together, separate the symbols)

Thanks

Comment: it's _not_ a duplicate like _at all_. It may appear like that, but I have edited the question to really show what OP wants (after answering the prequel question)

Comment: check my answer, it answers both questions now.

Answer (score 1):

You want to split characters of grouped non-alphanumerical characters.

I would create a 1-list item if the item is ok (alphanumerical) or a list of characters if the item is a sequence of symbols.

Then, I'd flatten the list to get what you asked for

```
import itertools

l = ['(', '44', '+(', '3', '+', 'll', '))']
new_l = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([x] if x.isalnum() else list(x) for x in l))
print(new_l)
```

result:

```
['(', '44', '+', '(', '3', '+', 'll', ')', ')']
```

EDIT: actually you could link your 2 questions into one answer (adapting the [regex answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330795/how-to-properly-split-this-list-of-strings/42330843#42330843) of the original question) by not grouping symbols in the regex:

```
import re
lst = ['z+2-44', '4+55+((z+88))']
print([re.findall('\w+|\W', s) for s in lst])
```

(note the lack of `+` after `\W`) and you get directly:

```
[['z', '+', '2', '-', '44'], ['4', '+', '55', '+', '(', '(', 'z', '+', '88', ')', ')']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Short solution using [***str.join()***](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [***re.split()***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) functions:

```
import re
l = ['(', '44', '+(', '3', '+', 'll', '))']
new_list = [i for i in re.split(r'(\d+|[a-z]+|[^\w])', ''.join(l)) if i.strip()]

print(new_list)
```

The output:

```
['(', '44', '+', '(', '3', '+', 'll', ')', ')']
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to change the regex in order to keep the non-alphanumeric characters separate :

```
import re
lst = ['z+2-44', '4+(55+z)+88']
[re.findall('\w+|\W', s) for s in lst]

#[['z', '+', '2', '-', '44'], ['4', '+', '(', '55', '+', 'z', ')', '+', '88']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re
lst = ['z+2-44', '4+(55+z)+88']
[re.findall('\w+|\W', s) for s in lst]
```

May be it helps to others.